# Formatting Dates in Google Apps Script and Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NUmU1i8R5GC2jvg6S-0mZbaul9Ql-kn4DPutgTUUB7w/edit?usp=sharing) that I building to manage my family's food storage. The main part I am using Google Apps Script for is to send me email alerts when something is within 60 days of expiring.

You can see the script by going to Tools > Script Editor (which you probably already assumed.)

I am having trouble with lines 74 and 80. When I run the script and check the log, I am getting 12/32/2015 and 11/31/2015. How can I get these to appear as 1/1/2016 and 12/1/2015?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Utilities.formatDate()`. [Read more](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) about Utilities class.

Replace line 74,

```
message1 += '1 ' + alertsArray[i][1] + ' of ' + alertsArray[i][0] + ' is going to expire on ' + (new Date(alertsArray[i][4]).getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (new Date(alertsArray[i][4]).getDate() + 1) + '/' + new Date(alertsArray[i][4]).getYear() + '. <br/>';
```

with this,

```
message1 += '1 ' + alertsArray[i][1] + ' of ' + alertsArray[i][0] + ' is going to expire on ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(alertsArray[i][4]), "GMT-07:00", "''MM/dd/yyyy")) + '. <br/>';
```

Do the same to line 80.

Comment: That does it. Thank you!